# In what sense did the Oklo reactor "trap" its own nuclear waste?

Tags: geology, earth-history, mineralogy

A number of popular writings on [the natural fission reactor at Oklo, Gabon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor) (e.g. [here](http://gizmodo.com/there-s-a-naturally-occurring-nuclear-fission-reactor-i-1475445638)) state that some of the energetic byproducts (krypton and xenon, presumably <sup>85</sup>Kr and <sup>133</sup>Xe) of the reactor were "trapped" in aluminophosphate.

How, exactly, does "aluminophosphate" (I assume this is some sort of framework mineral?) trap gaseous elements? Is it related to the mechanism by which clathrates trap gases?

Comment: Huh, I never even knew there was a natural nuclear reactor. Thanks for asking this question, I wouldn't have found out otherwise!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Record of Cycling Operation of the Natural Nuclear Reactor in the Oklo/Okelobondo Area in Gabon](http://presolar.wustl.edu/laboratory_for_space_sciences/Publications_2004_files/Meshik-PRL-04.pdf), the Xe is trapped in crystalline cage-like structures formed of the aluminum phosphate that are similar to [zeolites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeolite).

The reference also explains that the aluminum phosphate structures grow quickly under hydrothermal conditions of 270-300 degrees C.